# 2 Audio Elements with different SRC plays same file

Tags: html, audio, shoutcast

I am using SHOUTcast to broadcast multiple radio streams. For some reason when two audio elements exists on a single page, both plays the same source despite them being different.

Please see screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/0ZQ8XOKq

===

I am not understanding this.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what the difference was but I was able to get this working with this.. code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio controls id="1">
  <source src="http://live.soundcheck.xyz:8000/scur" type="audio/mp3">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<audio controls id="2">
  <source src="http://live.soundcheck.xyz:8000/r&b" type="audio/mp3">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```